# Help! Can not figure out syncing and playlists on iTunes.

Tags: itunes

I have tried to research this online but can't find anything helpful!  I thought the playlists (and everything else)  on iTunes always overwrote whatever was on the device. This worked great syncing music to both my husbands phone and my phone. ITunes always overwrote what was on our phone with what was on the computer. So if we created a new playlist in the computer then synced, it would be on our phones.

My daughter's phone had been synced and then she edited some playlists, made new ones, and deleted ones she didn't like. The next time she synced her phone, ALL of my playlists on iTunes changed to what was on her phone, meaning my husband and I lost most of our playlists!  We had to go and recreate ines we cared about, which was really frustrating. I did NOT think iTunes ever overwrote the computer with items from a device.

Most recently, I discovered that all my playlists on my phone only have one or two songs in them now. I still have all the music on my phone and have no idea what happened to my playlists. I can only imagine it happened when syncing but I never went and deleted my playlists. I am literally scared to ever sync my phone again. All my amazing playlists are just decimated, and you all know how much time can go into creating playlists.

I am just looking to understand HOW syncing of playlists is supposed to work. Do I create new playlists on my computer or on my phone?  Are they going to disappear the next time I do a sync?  Would appreciate any and all help. I can't understand why this isn't documented in iTunes help!

Comment: This depends to a fair extent on your particular scenario. You've provided a great background as to what's happened, but you really need to provide some more details about your situation. For example, do you subscribe to Apple Music? Do you have the iCloud Music Library enabled? If so, is it enabled on some or all devices? And what have you configured within iTunes on your computer? Do you use Apple's Family Sharing? Are you using the same or different Apple IDs? Finally, to the right of this question you'll see a whole list of _Related_ questions, so they may be worth exploring as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I do not subscribe to Apple Music. Do not have iCloud Music Library enabled. Have iTunes set to sync all music. Yes, I use Family Sharing and we all have different Apple ID's.